# Jquery - copy excel data into input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I am trying to copy excel columns into one input field that will then break up each excel cell into its own input field. I have it working somewhat but not with excel data.

For example, if i copy and paste '1 2 3 4 5' into one input field, it will take each value and paste it into a separate input field.

Example:
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZBXR.jpg

If i copy and paste the data like the example below, it does not work:

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXwRp.jpg

Check out the jsfiddle for an example
https://jsfiddle.net/jdarville/rfsn1sz4/

```
$("#templateinfo").bind("paste", function(e){
            // access the clipboard using the api
            var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
            arr = pastedData.split(' ');
            for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
                $("#temp"+i).val(arr[i]);
            }
        } );
```

Its splitting the data by ' ' and if i copy and paste excel data it has a space between information but its not working.

Comment: Wouldn't excel data have tab, not space?